# How to change symbol separating description item definitions with enumitem

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I'm trying to alter the `description` environment with `enumitem` so that an item will be separated from its description by a dash rather than a colon. Having searched the documentation and this forum, I haven't found a solution. The closest I've come is this:

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, format= --]
```

That puts the en-dash before the item, rather than after; not what I need.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to redefine the `\makelabel` command:

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=\parindent,
  leftmargin=*,labelsep=.33333em,
  before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1 --}}]
```

The setting of `labelsep` should produce a normal interword space.

Comment: That worked perfectly; thanks. Is the `\makelabel` command specific to `enumitem` and where can I find its documentation? Since reading your answered I've gleaned a little more out of the `enumitem` documentation, but not enough to understand how I would use the command in other situations.

Comment: @pyrogerg The `\makelabel` command tells LaTeX how to typeset the argument to `\item` (in this case), which is passed to `\makelabel`. In this case you need to refer to the argument as `##1`, because the redefinition is performed inside a definition.